# Django migration error table is already exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

1. Hi i have only one migration file called 001_initial..... it contains all create table(sql) django makemigrations created when i did makemigrations for example 5 tables [1,2,3,4,5]
2. and i have first(1) already there in my database for example 1,
3. so i need to migrate table for example 2,3,4,5
4. but i'm getting error when i do python manage.py migrate, error is table one(1) is already created and table 2,3,4,5 not created in the database because of this error
5. i have only one migration file and i deleted the django_migration file  data
6. Error is `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'sfff_tyu' already exists")`

so how to do?

Comment: Can you share your migration file and the exception you get in detail?

Comment: You cannot have a migration in which half is already migrated and half is not. If you want to run this, divide your migration in two files. First should contain migration which is already migrated. You should fake it and second should contain migrations which have to be migrated.

Comment: @cagrias its normal migration file i had 5 models i created and one migration file contains all 5 table query from python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: @MuhammadHassan means for table 1 query put in main 0001 initial file and remaing 4 table query create new second migration put decencies on 001 _initial_file. an first migration file fake it second migration file migrate ?

Comment: @madukp Yes because django only keep record of which migration is executed and which is not. Check django_migrations table in your database.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan is there any harm(means errors) second migration table  contains forginkey on something ??

Comment: If table in 2nd migration has dependency on table in 1st, then there may be some error. I am not sure. But you can try it on local system.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to lose your data in your first table, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your 0001 migration file and delete the create table commands for table 2,3,4,5 (**except** table 1). (Make a copy of that file in case things don't go well)
2. Run command `python manage.py makemigrations {your_app_name}`. (This will create a migration file 0002 containing the create table queries for table 2,3,4,5.
3. Run `python manage.py migrate {your_app_name}`.